# Looping in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

```
<body>    
{% for topic in topics %}
        <p>Topic:<br></p>
        <h3>{{ topic.text }}:</h3>
        <p>date added: {{ topic.date_added }} </p>
        {% entries = topic.enrty_set.all %}  <<---- this is line 12 (error line)
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <p>{{ entry }}</p>
        {% endfor entries %}
    {% endfor topic %}
</body>
```

Error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at / Invalid block tag on line 12: 'entries', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

How do I make inner for loop? Looks like I can't assign query set to a variable like this. How do I do this? I can't really do it in views ether. The Goal is to display all the Entries for every Topic I have.

Code works in: $ python manage.py shell

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Jinja2, the Django template language does not support setting a variable inside the template. For you purpose, you can simply iterate over `topic.entry_set.all` directly instead:

```
{% for entry in topic.entry_set.all %}
    <p>{{ entry }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```